# Rails Model Validation Hangs Up PUT Request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have this in my User.rb Model to format the User's subdomain properly before saving:

```
def subdomain=(c)
   write_attribute(:subdomain, c.tr('^A-Za-z0-9', '').downcase) 
end
```

But when I do a client-side (backbone) PUT request to the API, updating attributes that do not include the Subdomain...

```
Request Payload: { bg_hue: "359", id: 4 }
```

..the above custom Model validation is causing a 500 response, with the following error specified:

```
NoMethodError at /user/4=================================> undefined method `tr' for nil:NilClass
```

Meaning, it is hanging on the c.tr line in the Model

I guess I can check if the request includes a subdomain in the controller first and then try saving it with or without the subdomain, which I think should get around the above problem, but then again, I'm not entirely sure what the problem is.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you `` undefined method `tr' for nil:NilClass ``.  The issue is that the value `c` being passed in is `nil`.  You should probably do something like:

```
def subdomain=(c)
   write_attribute(:subdomain, c.tr('^A-Za-z0-9', '').downcase) unless c.nil?
end
```